# Azure Pipeline with a bash expression inside condition

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

How to use a bash script in the condition?

```
- bash: export PYTHONPATH="src/"
  condition: succeeded(fileExists('./src/'))
  displayName: Add src/ Path if Exists
```

`condition: succeeded(fileExists('./src/'))` this seems not working, it shown the following error message below:

```
##[error]Unrecognized value: 'fileExists'.
```

Comment: I agree with Shayki's answer. Until now, azure devops can only support use variable in condition, and few of [functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#functions). But it does not contain **fileExists**. You need make it get associate with variable, then you can succeed to apply in condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditions not works like that, you can check variables values there, [check the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

So, if you want to check if file exist you need to add another script task that check if the file exist, if yes set a variable, than use this variable in the conditions.

Something like this:

```
- bash: |
   if [ -f /tmp/foo.txt ]; then
       echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=fileExist]true"
   fi

- bash: export PYTHONPATH="src/"
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['fileExist'], 'true'))
```

Comment: seems the fileExist variable it not created, `Evaluating: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['fileExist'], 'true'))
Expanded: and(True, eq(Null, 'true'))
Result: False`

Comment: @SLN check if the code inside the `if` is running, add `echo` there.

Comment: I think each bash creates a new session, when a bash task is finished the session is closed and the variable is no longer exist